# How to set the on UITableView cell width different from the selection of segment button in objc on one view using only one cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I Have a view in which a segment controller ,I have used with two selection.
So here I just want to increase the width of cell containing label with address on first selection rather decrease the width by second selection,and here I used one cell and also using autoresizing in it.
Views are attached in it.Please have a look[View on selection of second segment index 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n71dm.png)

[Views on selection of second segment index 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhfra.png)

Comment: Simple give the tag both segment According tag you can set width and height of your tableview cell

Comment: I did this already but it does not work ,Because  the cell is reusable after the scrolling only.

Comment: Yes cell become reusable  When your cell become alloc than set the condition for both segment . if (segment ==1) cell alloc if(segment. ==2)cell alloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it as that you want the address to fill the space taken up by the price when there is no price to show, there I suggest to:

**Use Constraints**

You can set a constraint for space between the address label and the price label.
Then a constraint between the price label and the trailing margin.
On scenarios where you **do not** need the price, set it's width to 0 and the address will stretch to fill up the space.

And since you are reusing the cell, remember to reset the width in `prepareForReuse` of the cell.

Comment: Thanks, For your answer ,But in it i do not use constraint ,I have to use the autoresizing because it is too oldest project.

Comment: I haven't yet met a situation where auto resizing is a must, maybe you can elaborate on the exact result you want. I might have an extend solution that fulfils that extra need too.